# UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create multiple subplots of boxplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(7, 2)
for ax, feature in zip(axs.flatten(), df.columns):
    
    title = "column: {}".format(feature)
    df.boxplot(column=feature, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(title)               
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting too tight plots:
[image]

When trying to use `tight_layout` I'm getting warrning:

```
UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations
```

How can I display the subplots in a readable way ?

Comment: MAke the figure bigger with the figsize kwarg to subplots   Also suggest constrained_layout versus tight_layout.

Comment: Probably better to correctly use `pandas.DataFrame.plot`. `df.plot(kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(7, 2), figsize=(7, 10)); plt.tight_layout()`. And make sure you're using a current version of matplotlib (3.4.2).